# Fazer uma subconsulta SQL

Tags: sql

Estou tentando fazer várias consultas (contando a quantidade de determinados elementos) dentro uma mesma coluna da tabela, e mandar cada consulta para uma coluna diferente.
Ex: Tenho coluna de nomes, e eu quero consultar a quantidade de alguns sobrenomes como: quantidade de "Silva", "Alves" e "Santos". E criar uma coluna "Silva" com o número de nomes com Silva, e etc.

O que pensei:

```
SELECT COUNT(`coluna_1`) AS `Nome`

(SELECT COUNT (`coluna_1`) AS `Nome_1`
FROM `Tabela_1` AS `A`
WHERE (`A`.`coluna_1` LIKE '%nome_1%')

FROM `Tabela_1` AS `B`
WHERE (`B`.`coluna_1` LIKE '%nome%'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá, tudo bem?
O que tu busca pode ser facilmente atingido com a seguinte consulta (bem parecida com a que tinhas pensado inclusive):

```
select (select count(nome) from Pessoas where nome like '%Silva%') as Silva,
       (select count(nome) from Pessoas where nome like '%Alvez%') as Alvez,
       (select count(nome) from Pessoas where nome like '%Santos%') as Santos
```

Espero que tenha ajudado ;)

Answer (score 4):

Em alguns SGBDs é possível realizar um filtro ao utilizar uma função de agregação, como o count. Isto evita a realização de diversas consultas aninhadas.

Em [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-expressions.html), por exemplo, a sua consulta poderia ser escrita da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT
       count(nome) FILTER (WHERE nome like '%Silva%') as Silva,
       count(nome) FILTER (WHERE nome like '%Alves%') as Alves,
       count(nome) FILTER (WHERE nome like '%Santos%') as Santos
FROM tabela
```

Em outros SGBDs é possível usar uma clausula CASE WHEN da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT
       count(CASE WHEN nome like '%Silva%' THEN 1 END) as Silva,
       count(CASE WHEN nome like '%Alves%' THEN 1 END) as Alves,
       count(CASE WHEN nome like '%Santos%' THEN 1 END) as Santos
FROM tabela
```

[Aqui um exemplo executável dos códigos descritos](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/211).